# Pagination with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api

i'm working with React-App and backend/frontend API i get the response everything works fine , but i get too many responses ( over 100 ) at once, how can i go about only getting lets say ( 10 ) at a time, i've tried many things but they dont work. this is my code.

***NOT ASKING FOR SOMEONE TO DO THE CODE FOR ME, BUT FOR A LITTLE HELP PUTTING ME ON THE RIGHT DIRECTION***

***REST API***

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'


const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3008';

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url });

export const playersAPI = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'playersAPI',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getplayersAPI: builder.query({
            query: (count) => createRequest(`/api/players?limit=${count}`),
        }),
        
    })
});

export const { useGetplayersAPIQuery } = playersAPI;
```

***Front Page***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import millify from 'millify';
import { Typography, Row, Col, Statistic } from 'antd';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Card } from 'antd';


import { useGetplayersAPIQuery } from '../services/playersAPI';


const { Title } = Typography;

const Players = ({ simplified }) => {
  const count = simplified ? 10 : 100;
  const { data: playersList, isFetching } = useGetplayersAPIQuery(count);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState();
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  console.log(players)

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlayers(playersList?.players);
    const filteredData = playersList?.players.filter((name) => name.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));

    setPlayers(filteredData);
  }, [playersList, searchTerm]);

  if (isFetching) return 'Loading...';

  

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-crypto">
        <input placeholder="Search Players" onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <Row gutter={[15, 15]} className="crypto-card-container">
        {players?.map((name) => (
          <Col xs={24} sm={12} lg={6} className="crypto-card" key={name.id}>
            <Link to={`/players/${name.id}`}>
              <Card
                title={`${name.name}`}
                hoverable
              >
                <p>Name: {(name.name)}</p>
                <p>Status: {(name.status)}</p>
                <p>Alliancce: {(name.alliance)}</p>
              </Card>
            </Link>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </>
  )
}

export default Players
```

This is my front page the squares the ones i want to show only 10 of them at a time, right now it shows all the data from the API.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKHLi.jpg]

Comment: Just to understand the problem. Do you want to create local pagination (Requesting a specific number of elements and paginating only that amount of elements in the frontend) or create a backend function that receives limit and offset to paginate?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your backend to add an extra parameter offset, you can do something like this.

```
const PlayersScreen = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [playersPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPlayers = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      const data = await res.json();
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false)
    };
    fetchPlayers();
  }, []);

  // Get current players
  const indexOfLastPlayer = currentPage * playersPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPlayer = indexOfLastPlayer - playersPerPage;
  const currentPlayers = data.slice(indexOfFirstPlayer, indexOfLastPlayer);

  // Change page
  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  return (
    <div className='container mt-5'>
      <h1 className='text-primary mb-3'>My Players</h1>
      <Players players={currentPlayers} loading={loading} />
      <Pagination
        playersPerPage={playersPerPage}
        totalPlayers={data.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Players = ({ players, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <ul className='list-group mb-4'>
      {players.map(player => (
        <li key={player.id} className='list-group-item'>
          {player.title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

const Pagination = ({ playersPerPage, totalPlayers, paginate }) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPlayers / playersPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className='pagination'>
        {pageNumbers.map(number => (
          <li key={number} className='page-item'>
            <a onClick={() => paginate(number)} href='!#' className='page-link'>
              {number}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: i added a picture of my front page landing, so you can see what i want to do, theres the squares that right now show 100 of them or more, i want to only show 10 of them, i tried your code, but it still shows all of the records

Comment: @yandrysantana, I made some changes to the example code, maybe this is something that you can use to do local pagination.